# Relaying JDA events to Spring Event subsystem hangs whole Spring app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, discord-jda

I'm trying to make a command framework for a Discord Bot using Spring Boot with Kotlin. I got it working perfecly with Javacord but recently I decided to switch to JDA and I've hit a snag. The command framework I'm making also relays all Discord events to the Spring Event system and what I'm currently doing is grabbing the generic event listener (https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/core/hooks/EventListener.html) and dispatching everything to Spring, using an autowired `ApplicationEventPublisher`. However, the spring app seems to hang on that line, and after debugging it with some breakpoints it seems that it gets stuck on this particular line (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/event/AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java#L190). Any idea why this is happening? I've seen this (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20904) but I'm not sure what to do...

`SpringGenericEventPublisher.kt`

```
@Component
class SpringGenericEventPublisher : EventListener {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var context: ApplicationEventPublisher

    override fun onEvent(event: Event) = context.publishEvent(event)
}
```

`BotConfiguration.kt` (where I have the bean that builds the JDA instance)

```
    @Bean
    fun bot(config: BotProperties): Bot = JDABuilder()  // [Bot] is a typealias for [JDA]
        //.setCallbackPool(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())  // I've tried this because of the issue I linked above, but I got the same result
        .setToken(config.token)
        .addEventListener(springGenericEventPublisher)
        .build()
```

Then I have a simple listener just to test

```
@Component
class FooComponent {
    @EventListener(Event::class)
    fun onFoo(event: Event) {
        println("Reached `onFoo`")
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

PS: I should add that I'm also using Spring Data Redis and Spring Data MongoDB and that both fire up with success before that and that the command registry should start after that, just doesn't. The JDA instance logs in perfectly, since if I just print something to the screen instead of publishing the event on `SpingGenericEventPublisher` it will succeed.